# New Relic and Google Analytics browser stat discrepency

Tags: google-analytics, newrelic

I'm tracking a client website with both Google Analytics and New Relic. 
There's a bit of discrepency between the browser usage though (i think).

Google Analytics reports Chrome as top used browser, followed by IE with almost half number of sessions:

[image]

New Relic doesn't have a comparative metric, but it reports 1.6 times higher **throughput** for IE than Chrome:

[image: No other useful metric here]

I understand that "number of sessions" and "pages per minute" by browser are not directly comparable: sessions are recorded only after ga script is fully loaded and throughput includes requests by bots or some non-user-accountable hits.

But besides that, could there be another explanation? If throughput for IE is so high, it should be either due to high number of sessions or pages/session, but both of which are lower compared to Chrome (according to GA).

Answer (score 1):

New Relic has a troubleshooting doc on this topic ([Browser data doesn't match other analytics tools](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/browser/new-relic-browser/troubleshooting/browser-data-doesnt-match-other-analytics-tools)) that might shed some light on why this is.

*A few other ideas for investigation:*

As you note, and on the screenshot above the Sessions and Pages/Session are both lower for IE from GA, and higher in NR.  But if you want to drill in a bit and try to compare more apples-to-apples, you might want to take a look at Google Analytic's Page View metrics as opposed to Session-level report.  You can find this in Google Analytics Reporting under:

```
Behavior -> Site Content -> All Pages...
Page View metric...
Primary Dimension: Other -> Technology -> Browser
```

From the New Relic end, you  could take a look at [New Relic Insights](https://newrelic.com/insights) for the underlying browser metric data to see if anything stands out that could be contributing the to difference.

Probably an obvious point, but it's worth double checking that the Google Analytics data and New Relic data is for the same time period.